# How can I know if a window belongs to my program? Using win32 only

Tags: windows, winapi

How can I know if a window belongs to my program? I guess I can use the window handle to get the executable name but that seems like a lot of work and I have to do this repeatedly so I think it might be a performance issue. Is there a simple way to know if a given window handle is from ones own program with win32 or some OS construct? Can't use window titles either due to the nature of this application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522(VS.85).aspx) and compare the returned process Id against your own (via [GetCurrentProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683180(VS.85).aspx)) seems simple.